# how to convert date string to normal readable date

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have `date` `string` which looks like this `2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z`

I want this date string to be in readable format like this `DD/MM/YYYY`

I tried something like this but giving `error`  .

```
var formattedDate = new Date('2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

please help me to get the `formated` `date`

thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: In *2017-11-09*, `11` is a month or a day?

Comment: @TimGerhard, i'm getting this `error`  `intermediate value).format is not a function
`

Comment: @gurvinder372 The format is ISO 8601, so 11 would always be the month. There would only be ambiguity if it had been presented as 09/11/2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to do it.

```
var date = moment('2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 2):

A useful and flexible way for formatting the DateTimes in javascript is:

```
var date = new Date('2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z');
// optional: hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short'
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(date));
```

Result: "09/11/2017"

In this way, you can customize all dates.

an alternative way is(without options):

```
var formattedDate=new Date('2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z').toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Result: "09/11/2017"

Good Luck

[Check Online](https://jsbin.com/hezebubuwa/3/edit?js,console)

Comment: Note that the question asked for DD/MM/YYYY, which is not US date format.

Comment: @Adrian Wragg oooooh, you are right. the wanted date format is 'DD/MM/YYYY' not 'MM/DD/YYYY'. I change it to 'en-GB'(British English) for 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`substring` -> `split` -> `reverse` -> `join`

```js
var input = "2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z"
var output = input.substring(0,10).split("-").reverse().join( "/" );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: In Spite of good answer but it's a little complex. please look at my answer.I hope it helps you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46724073/7487135)

Answer (score 1):

```
var date= new Date(`2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z`);
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var date= dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
console.log(date);//it logs "09/11/2017"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Use this Function 

   function dateFor(value) {  
            if(value==null) {
                return '-' 
            } else {    
                var date = new Date(value); 
                var dates = date.toDateString();
                var datess = dates.split(' ');     
                if(date.getMonth()+1>=10) {
                    return datess[2]+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3];
                } else {      
                    return datess[2]+'-'+'0'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3];
                }
            }    
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateString = '2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z'
var date = new Date(dateString);
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
console.log( day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery dateFormat Js Plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dateFormat/1.0/jquery.dateFormat.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var shortDateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
            var date1 = "2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z";
            var date2 = jQuery.format.toBrowserTimeZone(date1,shortDateFormat);
            alert(date2);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a way that simply works on string manipulation, then you could use a regular expression to take the relevant parts out:

```js
var formattedDate = "2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z"
var result = formattedDate.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*$/, "$3/$2/$1");
console.log (result);
```

The first parameter captures a four-digit number and two two-digit number, while the second parameter includes the relevant placeholders.

However, you're dealing with a date, so by far the **best** way would be to use the date formatting functions mentioned in the answers to [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

```
let d = new Date('2017-11-09T05:36:00.834Z');
var formatted = `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth() + 1}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
```